# Curses horizontal printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses, python-curses

Hello I am trying to use the **curses** library in **python 3.5.2**. My OS is **Ubuntu 16.04**. When I initialize the library, My terminal begins moving horizontally every time I hit enter. If anyone has any advice or things i can try, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import curses
>>> stdscr = curses.initscr()
>>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>>
```

Comment: you have entered curces mode. try to type - no echo - print("\r\n") and you will have a new line. curse is no really useful in python terminal, it is more useful for console based application (#TUI)

Comment: the print command allowed me to get to a new line. Thank you for the help and advice. I will look for a different library.